# Is there a way to check if a GameObject within a list of GameObjects is destroyed (Unity, 2D)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a list of enemies (GameObjects). I want a door to be locked until they are all dead. I am using a public list of the enemies (so I can reuse this concept later in the game).

```
public GameObject fightBarrier;
public List<GameObject> enemies = new List<GameObject>();
public SpriteRenderer Barrier_0;
public SpriteRenderer Barrier_1;
public SpriteRenderer Barrier_2;
public SpriteRenderer Barrier_3;
public Sprite Barrier;
public Sprite noBarrier;

private int enemiesAmountCheck;

// overrided because it's inheriting from another script
protected override void OnCollide(Collider2D coll)
{
   if (coll.name == "Player")
   {
      enemiesAmountCheck = enemies.Count;
      for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count - 1; i++)
      {
         // This if statement has to check if the GameObject doesn't exist (AKA the GameObject is None)
         if (enemies[i]... )
         {
            enemiesAmountCheck = enemiesAmountCheck - 1;
         }
      }
      if (enemiesAmountCheck > 0)
      {
         fightBarrier.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = true;
         Barrier_0.sprite = Barrier;
         Barrier_1.sprite = Barrier;
         Barrier_2.sprite = Barrier;
         Barrier_3.sprite = Barrier;
      }
      else
      {
         fightBarrier.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
         Barrier_0.sprite = noBarrier;
         Barrier_1.sprite = noBarrier;
         Barrier_2.sprite = noBarrier;
         Barrier_3.sprite = noBarrier;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After you destroy a GameObject, the index in the array should become null. So, you could say `if(enemies[i]==null)`, and that should return true if the enemy object has been destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Yep!

```cs
for(int x = 0; x < enemies.Count; x++) // Loop through list
{
    if (enemies[x] == null)
    {
       enemies.RemoveAt(x);//When object is destroyed it will be set null
    }
}
```

Comment: This will jump the elements right after each removal. Iterate from end to start to avodi that.